# VBA copying data from one sheet to many sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have one row of data that I want to automatically copy to all the other sheets as they are automatically being created. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made one change to your code:  "With Application.Sheets(i)". Excel just didn't know which sheet to put that text on.  :)

```
Sub DayAdder()
DaysInMonth = "Enter Days"
Counter = Application.InputBox(DaysInMonth)
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count), Count:=Counter
CurMonth = "Enter The Month"
newName = Application.InputBox("Name", CurMonth, "", Type:=2)
For i = 1 To Application.Sheets.Count
    Application.Sheets(i).Name = newName & " " & i
    With Application.Sheets(i)
        .Range("A1").Value = "NAME"
        .Range("B1").Value = "AGE"
        .Range("C1").Value = "JOB"
        .Range("D1").Value = "OCCUPATION"
        .Range("E1").Value = "FAMILY"
        .Range("F1").Value = "WORK"
        .Range("G1").Value = "FRIEND"
    End With
Next

End Sub
```

I also added a space between the sheet name and the number, so it's "July 1" instead of "July1".

If this solves your problem, please mark it as The Answer!  :)

Comment: You're welcome! Thanks for marking my answer as The Answer!  :)

Comment: Quick question, instead of having the user enter in the CurMonth, is there a way to create a dropdown menu with the month names and when the user selects a name, it get put on all the sheets?

Comment: I could probably write code to grab the current month, but I don't know how to create a drop-down.  You could create a form (which is probably overkill!), and I think there's also an option to create a validation list drop-down in a cell, but I haven't created one in years.